# Apps not updating in iPad Air 3rd generation

Tags: ios, ipad, over-the-air

We are distributing the app through OVERTHEAIR distribution. We are pushing all updates through it.

For example: Consider we have installed some xyz app with version number 4.1. Some updates are coming into the app saying version is 4.2.

When we hits update its not updating in iPad air 3 rd generation.

Once we delete the existing app from the device, then the latest version is getting installing in the ipad Air 3.

Updates are installing properly in other devices. We are wondering why its not installing in iPad air alone.

We are using the same provisioning profile and bundle identifier

OS Version : 10.3

Thanks well in advance if some one helps on this

Comment: There is [no such device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471) as iPad Air (3rd generation). Do you mean [iPad (5th generation)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP751?locale=en_US)?

Comment: http://tablets.specout.com/compare/125-266/Apple-iPad-3rd-Gen-vs-Apple-iPad-Air